# PLAY Framework not finding sbtconfig.txt

Tags: playframework, installation

Im trying to use the Play framework and i cant initialize it because the sbtconfig.txt i not found . Can someone help with this??? I have a clean install in10 with java 1,8sdk isntalled.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean build.sbt？ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfM3p.png)

every file should be all right while you create a new play project